# Is there an acceptable workflow scenario for promoting Terraform .tfplan files through different environments (dev through production)?

Tags: terraform

I am new to Terraform so bear with me. This scenario applies to the big 3 cloud providers. A colleague wants a pipeline that generates a .tfplan, then the .tfplan file is "promoted" on through QA, staging, production. Bear in mind that these environments have different resource names and object GUIDS (naturally) and tags according to the environment.

As far as I know, this won't work because the plan file references can get quite specific based on the existing resources that need to be dealt with, in each respective environment.

I know about Workspaces in TF. <s>I'm not looking to be referred to that, at this time.</s> Let's assume they are not an option because the more senior colleague considers them a configuration headache. I just can't find any documented TF workflow where this is even feasible .. but besides that, it makes no sense. Another issue with that paradigm is that it implies that the dev environment would need to scale resources the same way you would want to eventually scale it in production. In essence ... one would be developing the scaling plan then moving it through QA, etc to production .. thereby inextricably tying scaling needs in production, to dev.  Am I wrong?

Comment: `.tfplan` is meant to be generated and applied within the same workflow or pipeline. It is not meant to be re-used across different infrastructure environments. You would promote configs across environments and/or workspaces and/or git branches. Also note there is no standard extension for the binary `plan` output file. `.tfplan` was just adopted as a convention in the documentation after I randomly gave it that extension as part of the Jenkins Pipeline library for Terraform and Hashi reviewed it.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Thats what I thought. The colleague is pretty adamant about his paradigm so I needed this sanity check!

Answer (score 0):

In a normal Terraform workflow, the artifact that you might "promote" through various deployment stages is the configuration (the tree of module directories containing `.tf` files), not the plan files.

A "plan" in Terraform is a set of actions that providers are proposing in order to make the remote system match the new configuration, by comparing the configuration with the previous state. Each deployment stage will have its own "current state" and so each one will therefore needs its own plan created, although you can use the same configuration for each one in order to tell Terraform that the *desired state* is the same, even though the steps to reach that state may vary between the environments depending on how the relevant objects are already configured.

Terraform has some safety checks that aim to catch when you try to apply a saved plan file against a different state snapshot than you created it against, so in most cases doing this will just immediately return an error. However, Terraform's heuristics for detecting that can't be perfect (it's working with incomplete information) so it's still a good idea to take care to use a saved plan file only in the context for which it's intended.

Answer (score 0):

> I know about Workspaces in TF. I'm not looking to be referred to that,
> at this time. I just can't find any documented TF workflow where this
> is even feasible

Sorry to say that, but a workspace is definitely what you need. I'll post some examples that might be helpful, I've been working with TF for a few years ago.

Taking into consideration you have multiple envs in the same AWS account, you can have something like:

main.tf:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
bucket = "my-bucket-${local.env}"
  tags = {
    Environment = local.env
  }
}
```

settings.tf:

```
locals {
  env = terraform.workspace
}
```

With that, you need to create the workspaces:

```
terraform workspace create dev
terraform workspace create prod
```

When `prod` workspace is selected, a terraform plan will show something like that:

```
# aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
      + bucket                      = "my-bucket-prod"
      + tags                        = {
          + "Environment" = "prod"
        }
    }
```

and when `dev` is selected:

```
# aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
      + bucket                      = "my-bucket-dev"
      + tags                        = {
          + "Environment" = "dev"
        }
    }
```

So you will be able to create an S3 resource for each workspace you have without duplicating them. This is a simple approach to using the workspace, but if you are working with CI, you can pass a `$ENVIRONMENT` env var for instance and use it to select the right workspace.

```
        terraform workspace select $ENVIRONMENT
        terraform apply --auto-approve
```

If you are using multiple accounts, just tell me and I can edit my answer to put some examples. :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of how workspaces work and why we need them. The basic validation I needed is that .. the plan file is not to be considered immutable. The co-worker insists that the plan file can be developed into an immutable "release" and checked into source control .. then moved through environments as if it's a patch release. As long as the TF community in general regards that paradigm as nonsense, I can safely feel like I'm not misunderstanding what I've learned about TF so far.